# Calling AppleScript from Python without using osascript or appscript?

Tags: python, macos, applescript

Is there any way to execute (and obtain the results of) AppleScript code from python without using the `osascript` command-line utility or [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) (which I don't really want to use (I think?) because [it's no longer developed/supported/recommended](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/status.html))?

Rationale: in [another question I've just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064957/how-to-check-in-applescript-if-an-app-is-running-without-launching-it-via-osa), I describe a strange/undesired behaviour I'm experiencing with running some AppleScript via `osascript`.  As I'm actually calling it from a python script, I wondered if there was a way to route around `osascript` altogether, since that seems to be where the problem lies - but appscript (the obvious choice?) looks risky now...

Comment: Why not the python [osascript package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/osascript/)? Was it not available at the time this question was asked?

Comment: Looks like that project [got started in October 2015](https://github.com/russianidiot/osascript.py/commit/33455e1a42f5c3a0361b4f1e5c6952ed8574f0fe), so no, it wasn't available in 2013.

But it looks good, yes - thanks! :-)

Comment: Because that's also just a wrapper around a subprocess call to the `osascript` utility.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the PyObjC bridge:

```
>>> from Foundation import *
>>> s = NSAppleScript.alloc().initWithSource_("tell app \"Finder\" to activate")
>>> s.executeAndReturnError_(None)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Accepted this answer as it has the fewest dependencies, although `py-applescript` also looks good.  :-)

Comment: Might want to fix the spelling of 'NSApplScript' to add the 'e' after 'Appl' - I pasted your code and it didn't work first time!

Comment: In case of ImportError: `No module named Foundation`, one may use `sys.path.append("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC")` before the import statement.

Answer (score 23):

PyPI is your friend...

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-applescript

Example:

```
import applescript

scpt = applescript.AppleScript('''
    on run {arg1, arg2}
        say arg1 & " " & arg2
    end run

    on foo()
        return "bar"
    end foo

    on Baz(x, y)
        return x * y
    end bar
''')

print(scpt.run('Hello', 'World')) #-> None
print(scpt.call('foo')) #-> "bar"
print(scpt.call('Baz', 3, 5)) #-> 15
```

Comment: Thanks - works great.  Shall add PyPi to my list of stuff I should know about.

Comment: PyPI is indeed your friend. Ever so helpful, ever so often!

Comment: Thanks for the example, helps explain is so much faster than the package doc.

Comment: Note: py-applescript depends on PyObjC for its OSAscript functionality

Answer (score 2):

If are looking to execute ["Javascript for Automation"](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook) (applescript's successor) in your python code, here's how to do it:

```py
script = None

def compileScript():
    from OSAKit import OSAScript, OSALanguage

    scriptPath = "path/to/file.jxa"
    scriptContents = open(scriptPath, mode="r").read()
    javascriptLanguage = OSALanguage.languageForName_("JavaScript")

    script = OSAScript.alloc().initWithSource_language_(scriptContents, javascriptLanguage)
    (success, err) = script.compileAndReturnError_(None)

    # should only occur if jxa is incorrectly written
    if not success:
        raise Exception("error compiling jxa script")

    return script

def execute():
    # use a global variable to cache the compiled script for performance
    global script
    if not script:
        script = compileScript()

    (result, err) = script.executeAndReturnError_(None)

    if err:
        # example error structure:
        # {
        #     NSLocalizedDescription = "Error: Error: Can't get object.";
        #     NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Error: Error: Can't get object.";
        #     OSAScriptErrorBriefMessageKey = "Error: Error: Can't get object.";
        #     OSAScriptErrorMessageKey = "Error: Error: Can't get object.";
        #     OSAScriptErrorNumberKey = "-1728";
        #     OSAScriptErrorRangeKey = "NSRange: {0, 0}";
        # }

        raise Exception("jxa error: {}".format(err["NSLocalizedDescription"]))
    
    # assumes your jxa script returns JSON
    return json.loads(result.stringValue())
```

Comment: JXA can't match AppleScript's functionality and was pretty much abandoned after its release, so I wouldn’t consider it a successor.

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize it was abandoned more than AppleScript. In what ways does it not match AppleScript's functionality? Curious to learn more.