# Passing a Python list of strings to Applescript?

Tags: python, list, applescript

I have a Python script that evaluates certain directories on my hard-drive for criteria matching files. It returns a list of strings, containing the file names.
In Applescript, I call the Python script with `do shell script "path-to-script.py"`.
If I print the list inside the Python script and run the script from Applescript, it appears as a single string *(i.e. "['string1', 'string2', ..., 'stringX']")* in the results dialog of the Script Editor App.

Does anybody know, how to pass this Python list to an identical Applescript list?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling AppleScript from Python without using osascript or appscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065162/calling-applescript-from-python-without-using-osascript-or-appscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to have the Python script print the list items on separate lines:

```
print("\n".join(list_of_files))
```

And in AppleScript, break those lines up into a list:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set list_of_files to text items of (do shell script "path-to-script.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good practice to save Applescript's text item delimiters to a variable first and restore them after you have done what you want. Also enclose it all in a try block to avoid leaving the text delimiters in an unexpected state for any other scripts that may be run. i.e.

```
try 
    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters 
    -- do your stuff
    --restore default delimiters:
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
on error
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
end try
```